# executing a pyz file thru SSH fails with invalid syntax. Why?

Tags: python, windows, ssh, zipapp

I want to execute a pyz file over SSH in this way:

```
cat test.pyz | ssh -M user@somehost python
```

The current output is this:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    PKimport sys
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**The host/endpoint is a Windows machine.**

I created the pyz file, from command line, in this way:

```
python -m zipapp test/
```

[Here is a link to the pyz file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SK26kUE_QOzyDrYGQ_kcaxmVxULFwGTn/view?usp=sharing)

The content of the test folder is

```
├── test
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── executor.py
```

**main**.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import executor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.execute(sys.argv)
```

executor.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def execute(args):
    print("hello world")
```

- If I execute the pyz file locally, it works.
- If I copy the pyz file to the Windows machine and run "python test.pyz", 
  it works as expected too.

  Any ideas what's happening?, how to solve it?

Comment: Does the output of  'Cat' keep your indentations?

Comment: It kinds of do that. Further research shows that "cat test.pyz | python" doesnt work too. So, the problem is not SSH, but the cat/pipe operation.